# Nested while loop doesn't loop as expected

Tags: php, loops

I has problem looping the second while Loop.It will only loop once.So I can only get the value for the first row for the second loop. Please help me to figure this out, I am a beginner.

```
<ul id="navbar">

     <?php
     $rel = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY category";
     $sql=$db->query($rel); 
     while($row = $sql -> fetch_array()){
     ?>

     <li><a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['category'];?></a> 

        <ul>

            <?php
            $sel = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category_id=".$row['category_id']." ORDER BY subcategory ASC";
            $sql=$db->query($sel);  
            while($row1 = $sql -> fetch_array()){
            ?>

            <li><a href="subcategory.php?id=<?php echo $row1['subcategory_id'];?>"><?php echo $row1['subcategory'];?></a></li>

            <?php }?>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <?php }?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting `$sql` for the inner loop, invalidating it for the outer one. Use another variable name for the SQL result identifier in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are keeping the results of the first query in the variable `$sql`

```
$sql=$db->query($rel);
```

But then, before the second loop, you overwrite that variable.

```
$sql=$db->query($sel);
```

Try declaring a new variable for the second use. Say, `$sql2`.

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my codes and helping me out...that was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you use the variable `$sql` for both queries. Rename the second one to `$sql2` for example.

Also, avoid using so many `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make a note of that...this was really helpful. Thank you for having a look at my codes.